# How to check for palindrome in a reversed string in javascript

Tags: javascript, reverse, palindrome

I need your help communty, i have written a code to reverse a function but the problem is that am not able to check for palindrome, any help will be appreciated.
here is the code to reverse a string

```
function reverseString(str) {
    return str.split("").reverse().join("");
};
```

the problem is how to check for palindrome am totally confused. Sorry community i am suppose to run it against a test and it is not passing properly, that's the problem.
Here is the Test spec wriiten in jasmine.

```
describe("Produce the reverse order of a word: ", function () {
  describe("Case for en empty string", function() {

    it("should return null for empty string", function() {
      expect(reverseString('')).toEqual(null);
    });

  });

  describe("Case for palindromes", function() {

    it("should return true for `anna`", function() {
      expect(reverseString('anna')).toEqual(true);
    });

    it("should return true for `NaN`", function() {
      expect(reverseString('NaN')).toEqual(true);
    });

    it("should return true for `civic`", function() {
      expect(reverseString('civic')).toEqual(true);
    });

  });

  describe("Case for normal words", function() {

    it("should return `skoob` for `books`", function() {
      expect(reverseString('books')).toEqual('skoob');
    });

    it("should return `nomolos` for `solomon`", function() {
      expect(reverseString('solomon')).toEqual('nomolos');
    });

    it("should return `csim` for `misc`", function() {
      expect(reverseString('misc')).toEqual('csim');
    });

  });

});
```

Here is a code written by a friend in ECMA6 and it works by using a single function block. i don't want to use his code so i don't look like copy cat and is against the rule anyway just want to write my own code. Though we are still allowed to write it in ECMA 5

here is his code

```
const reverseString = (stringToReverse) => {
    reversedString = "";

    if (stringToReverse) {
        for (i = String(stringToReverse).length; i >= 0; i--) {
            reversedString += stringToReverse[i];
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    if (reversedString.substring(9) === stringToReverse) {
        console.log(true);
        return true;
    }
    return `${reversedString.substring(9)}`;
};

module.exports = reverseString;
```

Comment: You are already reversing the string in `palindrome` function.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to catch palindromes such that one, you have to also remove characters like comma and dot. A simple way to do this is removing non-alphanumeric characters:

```
function palindrome(str) {
  var re = /[^0-9a-z]/gi;
  var lowRegStr = str.toLowerCase().replace(re, '');
  var reverseStr = lowRegStr.split('').reverse().join(''); 
  return reverseStr === lowRegStr;
}
palindrome("A man, a plan, a canal. Panama");
```

EDIT: the regex used by OP was already fine. So the question is not really necessary. Nothing to be done.

Comment: Thank you but how do i reverse and check for palindrome in a single block of function.

Comment: Edit: actually it indeed works. At first, I thought it was removing only whitespaces, but that regex also is fine

Comment: Alberto is not passing the test

Comment: You should use the `palindrome` function in the two first test cases ("Case for an empty string" and "Case for palindromes"), and not the `reverseString` function. But it is still odd because you were not using `reverseString`in the `palindrome` function, you just replicated the functionality.

Comment: Totall confused now, i was thinking i need to extend this

Comment: i thought i needed to extend this function to accomodate palindrome

Comment: function reverseString(str) {
    return str.split("").reverse().join("");
};

Comment: Maybe you just need to use `reverseString` in the `palindrome` function, and use `palindrome` function, instead of `reverseString` in the second test case ("Case for a palindrome"), since it compares the value of return to a boolean value. It would make more sense for the name of the functions

Comment: Well, I saw your edit with that code. Well, that function your friend made is confusing, because it can return either boolean or string (or null). It returns string (the reversed word) if the word is not palindrome and returns true otherwise. You should not follow his approach :p

Comment: Thanks @Alberto for opening my eyes please help me with the standard way to write the function

Comment: It seems to be messed up, because that function is making more than one thing and its name (`reverseString`) is misleading. Better having more functions, each one doing only one thing and doing well that thing. You can have that two functions `reverseString`and `isPalindrome` (this one using the `reverseString`), and create tests for both of them.

Comment: it is a staled home work but i just want to challenge myself and write it properly.

Comment: It is a nice exercise :)

Comment: We are not allowed to touch the test

Comment: In that case, the test expects the function to be "bad designed"

Comment: i wondered aswell i tried understanding his code but it was hell confusing . i asked him but he spat some shit that got me more confused.But just wandering how come his code passed through. i tried mine is having 4 failures out of 7

Comment: His code passes because it is really doing what the tests expect, returning true in case the string is palindrome, returning the reversed string if it is not, and returning null if the string is null. It is such a odd behaviour to be expected, but, yeah, if you can't touch the test, that is what needs to be done. You can use the logic from that `palindrome` function inside that `reverseString` function.

Comment: Sorry what logic in what palindrome function please?

Comment: In your function: function palindrome(str) {
  var re = /[\W_]/g;
  var lowRegStr = str.toLowerCase().replace(re, '');
  var reverseStr = lowRegStr.split('').reverse().join(''); 
  return reverseStr === lowRegStr;
}

Comment: the last three spec is failing

Comment: For make them to pass, you need to return the reversed string, in case it is not palindrome.